# Azure Iot Hub FeedbackReceiver ReceiveAsync is very slow (15 seconds) high latency

Tags: azure, response, azure-iot-hub

if I send a message (Cloud 2 Device) via the IoT-Hub:

```
var serviceMessage= new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello Device"));
serviceMessage.Ack = DeliveryAcknowledgement.Full;
commandMessage.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
await serviceClient.SendAsync("myDeviceID", serviceMessage);  //Send message here
```

And try to receive the acknoledgement from the client:

```
bool feedbackReceived = false;
while(!feedbackReceived){
  FeedbackReceiver<FeedbackBatch> feedbackReceiver = serviceClient.GetFeedbackReceiver();
  var feedbackBatch = await feedbackReceiver.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
  if(feedbackBatch != null)
    {
      feedbackReceived = feedbackBatch.Records.Any(fm => fm.OriginalMessageId == serviceMessage.MessageId);
      if (feedbackReceived)
        {
          await feedbackReceiver.CompleteAsync(feedbackBatch);
          feedbackReceiver = null;
        }
    }
}
```

My client gets the message immediatelly and sends an feedback:

```
DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(iotHubUri, new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(bridgeID, deviceKey), TransportType.Amqp);
Message receivedMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
await deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
```

It take up to 15 seconds until my Cloud gets the feedback.
If I send messages in a loop, then the first message needs something between 1 and 15 sconds and every following response needs exactly 15 seconds.

Why does that need so long? Can I change it?
The receive-method in my cloud gets an answer immediatelly:

```
var incommingMessage = eventHubReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
incommingMessage.Wait();
```

If the client sends a message:

```
var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("My Message"));
await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
```

A whole project with the problem is on gitHub:
https://github.com/Ben4485/Azure_IotHub_Get_Response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course 15 seconds are a lot. However, the feedback isn't a single message but always a batch (a JSON document with an array of feedback) that contains more feedbacks from more devices. It's possible that the system tries to acquire more feedback as possible before sending them to the system.

Paolo.

Comment: I work on the Azure IoT Hub team. I just wanted to confirm Paolo's response. As per current design, IoT Hub tries to batch feedback responses by waiting for 15 seconds or 64 feedbacks. Meeting either condition will cause it to send the feedback response back to the Service Client. Rajeev

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. I don't really like it, but now I at least know how the design is implemented.
In my opinion, there should be a choice between a batch and a single feedback...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Reducing the latency of the feedback message is on our feature backlog list.

Comment: This would be high on my wish list as well!  One of the scenarios I'm using is a 'ping/isalive' messaging thing.  I was hoping to send a command to a device with a full ack request and get feedback as soon as it's picked up.  Being able to set this on device level would be awesome

Comment: Looks like the ReceiveAsync method now accepts a TimeSpan as a parameter so that you can explicitly control the receive timeout.  We are seeing feedback come in quickly when it is set.